# Which MySQL Query to Select Product Based on Location

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Basic scenario: I have 3 types of product, several manufactures and based on the customer's location, the product comes from the closest manufacture. I have something that almost works but I think my tables need to be structured a little better.

Here is what I have currently:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mfr` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `zip_code` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `radius` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `mfr` (`id`, `zip_code`, `radius`) VALUES
(1, 72756, 500),
(2, 74030, 360),
(3, 74701, 325),
(4, 72947, 300),
(5, 73112, 40),
(6, 63077, 100),
(7, 63106, 75);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `models` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mfr_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `models` (`id`, `name`, `mfr_id`) VALUES
(1, 'model 1', 1),
(2, 'model 2', 2),
(3, 'model 3', 2),
(4, 'model 1', 6),
(5, 'model 2', 4),
(6, 'model 3', 4);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `distances` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `time_inserted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `mfr_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `miles` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `zip_code` (`zip_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

INSERT INTO `distances` (`id`, `time_inserted`, `zip_code`, `mfr_id`, `miles`) VALUES
(1, 1397522155, 72761, 1, 41),
(2, 1397522155, 72761, 2, 131),
(3, 1397522155, 72761, 3, 223),
(5, 1397522155, 72761, 5, 197),
(6, 1397522156, 72761, 6, 301),
(7, 1397522156, 72761, 7, 353),
(8, 1397522166, 72761, 4, 87);
```

Expected Result:
Zip code of 72761 should return mfr_id of 1 for model 1 with 41 miles, mfr_id of 4 for models 2 and 3 with miles of 87, but instead mfr_id of 2 is returned for models 2 and 3, even though the milage is 131, which is greater than 87.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e450b/1/0

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  m.name,
  d.miles,
  d.mfr_id
FROM distances d
  JOIN mfr ON mfr.id = d.mfr_id
    AND mfr.radius > d.miles
  JOIN models m ON m.mfr_id = mfr.id
-- get min miles per model
  JOIN (SELECT m1.name,min(d1.miles) miles
        FROM models m1
          JOIN distances d1 ON d1.mfr_id = m1.mfr_id
        GROUP BY m1.name
        ) md ON md.name = m.name
             AND md.miles = d.miles
WHERE d.zip_code = 72761
ORDER BY d.miles ASC
```